# Navigating the CLI: Go back N words

Tags: bash, command-line, emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm a Vim user, so I'm learning Emacs commands for use in the Bash CLI. I know that on *my* systems I can use Vim-keybindings in Bash but I'd like to learn how to use it effectively in its default configuration.

First order of business: Moving around. Let us assume that I've got the following on the CLI:

```
$ mv some_long_file_name.txt some_long_file_name_with_slight_change.txt
```

I'm at the end of the line and I'd like to go back 4 words. [In Emacs one would](http://www2.lib.uchicago.edu/keith/tcl-course/emacs-tutorial.html) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, <kbd>4</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> however on the Bash CLI <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> erases to the beginning of the line. How to perform the motion, then?

Add auxiliary question, if I may? Assuming that I had successfully completed a move command and I'd like to do it again. How might I do that? So if I contorted my fingers on 5 keypresses to move back 4 words, how might I move back another 4 words?

Note that I am interested in learning how to use the default configuration. I don't want to configure Zsh, Vim keybindings, or `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Alt-4</kbd> <kbd>Alt-B</kbd> (like in  `ksh` and `zsh`, and `tcsh` where they all most probably copied it from). That assumes the terminal sends the sequence of characters `ESC`, `4`, `ESC`, `b` upon those key presses. The same combination works in Emacs too, by the way.

I'm not aware that there's any way to repeat a motion (other than the search ones).

Using <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl-S</kbd> (except that for that one, for `bash` you may need to disable terminal `xon`) might be a more effective way to move the cursor around.

Comment: Very cool, thank you! Where, please, is this documented?

Comment: @dotancohen, see [info -f bashref -n 'Numeric Arguments'](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Numeric-Arguments.html), and the output of `bind -p | grep digit`